# The render result is not the active camera I chose

Tags: rendering, camera

I have 4 different cameras. But no matter which one I set as the active camera. It renders the different cameras as I chose. (for example, I want to render camera3 it render camera 1.) I tried to set the camera3 as the active camera but it's still not working.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you check right column on this page with "Related"?  Seems to me you can find answer there.

Comment: I did. But i can't find a similar situation like me.

Comment: This might be the most related answer[link](https://blenderartists.org/t/rendered-picture-is-not-what-active-camera-shows/393763/2). But I don't understand how he fixed it.

Comment: @vklidu I solved it by my self. I used video editing so it is the reason why it fixed in the same view. But still Thank you for your answer!

Comment: OK :) Can you provide full answer so others can benefit from your A? Like now I didnt understand your A, so probably others will feel the same. Thanks